2-adic valuations of $k\cdot 3^n-1$
I was just playing around with numbers of the form $3^n-1$, and noticed that their 2-adic valuations have a nice, understandable pattern:
$\left(v_2(3^n-1)\right)_{n\ge 1} = (1,3,1,4,1,3,1,5,1,3,1,4,1,3,1,6,1,3,1,4,...)$
This pattern follows immediately from the fact that the multiplicative order of $3$, modulo $2^k$, is $2^{k-2}$ (when $k\ge 2$).
Then, I changed the sequence to $(v_2(11\cdot 3^n - 1))_{n\ge 1}$. That sequence begins:
$\left(5,1,3,1,4,1,3,1,6,1,3,1,4,1,3,1,5,1,3,1,4,1,3,1,8,1,3,1,4,...\right)$
It's clearly the "same thing", but seems to be shifted. If we just look at the first couple of terms, we might think it's shifted by 7 places, but then we encounter an 8 far too soon. Then we might think it's shifted by 43 places, but we encounter a 16 far too soon (not pictured here). Fool me once, etc.; I'm not sure I can trust this to be a finite offset.
Is there any way to understand/predict what's going on here? Please understand that $k=11$ could take on different values. If $k$ is a power of 3, then it's predictable. If $k$ is $5$ or $7$, modulo $8$, then it's predictable. (That's why I used $11$, the first non-trivial example.) For the odd numbers that aren't so easily predictable, what can we say?

This might help.

If we view it as $ ( 8 + 3 ) \cdot 3^n - 1 $. What can we say about the $v_2$ value? Can we determine "most" of them?

@CalvinLin then I would be looking to compute $v_2(8\cdot 3^n - (3^{n+1}+1))$, and I would employ the property that $v_2(a+b)=\min{v_2(a),v_2(b)}$ when $v_2(a)\neq v_2(b)$.  Why are you asking me this, though? Do you know how to answer this question, or are you thinking aloud?

@Lucenaposition I'm looking at that link, and I see how to apply it if the $11$ weren't there, but with the $11$, I don't see how it works.

You have a slight typo so the result I'm thinking of doesn't immediately fall out. Write it as $8 \times 3^n + ( 3^{n+1} - 1) $, clearly $ v_2 ( 8 \times 3^n ) = 3$, so if $3 \neq v_2 ( 3 ^ {n+1} - 1 ) $, then we are done (which is 75% of the time). This leaves the case of $ 3 = v_2 ( 3^{n+1} - 1)$, which requires a bunch more work (and to be clear, I don't have an immediate answer).   $\quad $(The 2 upvotes lends some credence to the idea being worthwhile to pursue, but isn't a perfect indicator.)

@CalvinLin Oh my, good catch, thank you. Darn those minus signs, randomly mutating into plus signs in our minds and on our scratch paper.

As a possible way to continue, we could view it as $ (27-16) \cdot 3^n - 1  = 3^{n+3} - 1  + (-16  \cdot 3^n)$. So if $ v_2 ( 3^{n+3} - 1 ) \neq 4$, then we are done.   $\quad$ Maybe look into how the 8 appears, and if we can relate that to something else.

@CalvinLin it's interesting. The first approach you suggested accounts for each string of "$1,3,1$", but leaves the tricky numbers unknown. The second approach accounts for each string of "$1,3,1,4,1,3,1$", but leaves the tricky numbers unknown. This feels again like chasing the wind.

What's more, 11 is only going to appear as a sum or difference of a power of 2 with a power of 3 finitely many times.

The best way to understand the situation, for odd $k$ (even $k$ is trivial) is to decompose your expression, to wit:
$(k\cdot3^n)-1=k[(3^n-1)-(k^{-1}-1)]$
where $k^{-1}$ is the reciprocal of $k$ in $2$-adics. For instance, $k=11$ would give $k^{-1}=\overline{0111010001}1$, which when we subtract $1$ will give $k^{-1}-1=\overline{1110100010}$.
The factor $k$, being odd, contributes nothing to the valuation, so we concentrate on the factor in brackets. For the $k=11$ case being explored here, the number we found above for $11^{-1}-1$ has a valuation of $1$, so it will dominate when $3^n-1$ has a larger valuation ($n$ even). That's how the $1$'s get shifted from the odd positions to the even ones. When $3^n-1$ has $1$ as valuation with $n$ odd, combining it with $11^{-1}-1$ will give a difference with a larger valuation, and that larger valuation will then depend on how many bits cancel when the difference is taken. That cancellation count varies nonperiodically, so we can't assign a single shift globally to the valuations greater than $1$ when we append that $k=11$ factor to the exponential.
But there are patterns, which we can infer from $2$-adic logarithms.
Logarithms
Suppose that instead of $k=11$, we had chosen $k=3$. Then, of course, there would have been no problem; the sequence is clearly shifted globally by one unit. Similarly if $k$ is any power of $3$, then there would be a global shift of $\log_3k$ positions. For instance, $k=27$ would give a shift of three units globally. Note that since the $1$ entries are shifted from odd to even positions with $k=27$, there are valuation numbers (the $1$'s) that look like they are shifted by just one unit. This dovetails with $3$ having a $1$ in the units bit when converted to base $2$.
So what is the logarithm of $11$ to base $3$? There is no such logarithm in whole numbers, so there can't be a global shift. But we can calculate $\ln(11)$ and $\ln(3)$, or more precisely $\ln(-11)$ and $\ln(-3)$, via the Iwasawa definition and then divide the former by the latter. Carrying out the logarithm calculations to ten bits we find that both have two terminal zeroes, which can be cancelled out so that the quotient is defined to eight bits out of the original ten. The result of this calculation is
$\log_3(11)=\log_{(-3)}(-11)=...00100111_2.$
To interpret this we read the bits from right to left. If we take only the units bit then we get $1$, which corresponds to some single valuations being shifted by one unit: the $1$ valuations are flipped from odd to even positions just like we found above with the more elementary analysis. If we read five bits, getting $00111$, then we can infer that although a shift of seven positions does not apply globally, it does apply within some blocks of $2^5-1=31$ valuations (not necessarily right at the beginning). With all eight bits shown we can infer that there are blocks of $2^8-1=255$ valuations apparently shifted by thirty-nine positions. (The ninth bit from the right also happens to be $0$, so we can replace $2^8-1=255$ with $2^9-1=511$.)

Thank you for this answer; it's very helpful. I'm not familiar with p-adic logarithms, although I understand in principle what they should be. Can you recommend how I can learn to calculate them?

Start with the logarithm defined here. For odd arguments in 2-adics this works, provided we attach a sign to the argument: + for 1 mod 4, - for 3 mod 4.

The Iwasawa definition goes like this. To render $\ln a$, factor $a=p^v\omega(1+x)$ where $v$ is the valuation of $a$, $\omega$ is a root of unity whose last digit matches the last nonzero of $a$, and $1+x$ then gives a convergent series for the logarithm. Then $\ln(a)=\ln(1+x)$ calculated from the series. In $2$-adics the resulting logarithm is a number whose exponential is $\equiv1\bmod4$.

I don't believe the $\mod 4$ restriction is necessary since $\log(1+x)$ converges when $|x|_2<1$. Another perspective is $\log(-x)=\log(x)+log(-1)$ and $\log(-1)=0$ (in $\mathbb{Z}_2$!). I think the confusion is the exponential does have its radius of convergence $|x|_2<1/2$ which effectively forces a $\mod 4$ condition.
It seems fine to disregard that radius since $3^z=\exp(z\log(3))$ has $|z\log(3)|2\le 4^{-1}$ when $z$ is a p-adic integer. Alternatively if you're computing as $3^z=(1+2)^z=\sum{n\ge 0}\binom{z}{n}2^n$ then we just need $|z|_2\le 1$ which is also true for $\log_3(11)$.

Given an odd number $N$, both $\ln(N)$ and $\ln(-N)$ will give the same result from the Maclaurin series for $\ln(1+x)$, so all logaruthmic values are achievable by selecting the sign to match $+1\bmod 4$. This also matches the valuation of the logarithm to that of the argument and makes the logarithmic series converge faster.

The sequence for $k=11$ is not a finite offset of the $k=1$ case. My answer shares a bit in common with Oscar Lanzi's answer in terms of notation.
We can relate the two sequences by a translation in the p-adics by $x \mapsto x+\log_3(k)$,
$$v_2(k3^x-1) = v_2(3^{x+\log_3k}-1)$$
Let's assume now that the sequence we have, $(v_2(3^{n+\log_3k}-1))_{n \ge 1}$ ends up being a finite translate of the original sequence $(v_2(3^{n+m}-1))_{n \ge 1}$ for some integer $m$.
It's tempting at this stage to immediately jump to saying that because their valuations are equal that $\log_3k=m$ must also be equal, but we have to do a bit more work to show that. (For instance $|-x|=|x|$ for all $x$, but clearly $x\ne -x$.)
For convenience I switch to using the absolute value. So in terms of the absolute value, this means for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have, $|3^{n+\log_3k}-1|_2=|3^{n+m}-1|_2$. We can now use the ultrametric inequality to see that,
$$|(3^{n+\log_3k}-1)-(3^{n+m}-1)|_2 \le \max(|3^{n+\log_3k}-1|_2,|3^{n+m}-1|_2)$$
We can simplify a fair bit since the $|3^n|_2=1$ factors out, $3^{\log_3(k)}=k$, and the two terms in the max are equal,
$$|k-3^m|_2 \le |3^{n+\log_3k}-1|_2$$
Since $\mathbb{N}$ is dense in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, it means there is a sequence of natural numbers $n$ that converge to $-\log_3 k$, and so the right hand side of the inequality goes to $0$ in the limit. This means the constants on the left actually are $k=3^m$.
That shows that all finite shifts must have $k$ be an integer power of $3$.  Since $11$ isn't an integer power of $3$, there is no integer shift to get the $k=11$ sequence from the $k=1$ sequence.
Furthermore there is no periodic or eventually periodic "fix up" we can do on the sequence elements since $\log_3(11)$ is not rational. So trying to get a clean representation of the $k=11$ sequence in terms of the $k=1$ sequence is   equivalent to working out the digits of an irrational number.

"Furthermore there is no periodic or eventually periodic "fix up" we can do on the sequence elements since $\log_3(11)$ is not rational." But the logarithm does exist as a $2$-adics integer, which makes the shifts quasiperiodic.
